# Programmatically created TableView does not call cellForRowAt

Tags: swift, uitableview

i have a class that implements `UITableViewDelegate` and  `UITableViewDataSource` and i execute the following code:

```
let table = UITableView()        
table.rowHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.125
table.delegate = self
table.dataSource = self
let nib = UINib(nibName: "PrognoseTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main)
table.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "pcell")
table.reloadData()
table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
container.addSubview(table)


NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    table.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.leadingAnchor),
    table.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.bottomAnchor),
    table.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.topAnchor),
    table.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.2)
    ])
```

`container` and `rightContainer` are views of the current ViewController. the table is being shown correctly, except that it's cells are empty. also the function `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` that my class implements is not being called. `numberOfRowsInSection` is called however and returns 6.
What am i missing?

Comment: What about `numberOfSections(in:)` ?

Comment: also called. returns 1

Comment: Can you print your frame of the table ? If the frame of table is too small, cellForRowAt might not be called

Comment: By the way, I've noticed that you've added the table to `container`, but its constraints are made with `rightContainer`. Is that intended? Because it seems that it pins 3/4 of its sides to `rightContainer`.

Comment: the frame was all zeroes, but even if i initialize it with a frame that has correct height and width, it doesn't change anything. 
@EDUsta: yes that's intended. As i said, the table gets displayed correctly, but with blank cells

Comment: Can you show us more from your code?!

Comment: Check the row height, if it is zero than `cellForRowAt` will not work

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this issue and this is what i tried:

- Created a table in the view controller the same way you did. Implemented the delegate and datasource methods.

```
    class ViewController : UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet weak var rightContainer: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let table = UITableView()
            table.rowHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.125
            table.delegate = self
            table.dataSource = self
            table.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            let nib = UINib(nibName: "PrognoseTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main)
            table.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "pcell")
            table.reloadData()
            table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            container.addSubview(table)


            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                table.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.leadingAnchor),
                table.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.bottomAnchor),
                table.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightContainer.topAnchor),
                table.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.4)
                ])

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 6
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pcell") as! PrognoseTableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Test cell"
            return cell
        }
    }
```

[image: This was the result on running it on a simulator]